# Transform union of intersecting events into union of disjoint events

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose I have a union of of intersections of events defined as follows:

$A=(E_{1,1} \cap E_{1,2} \cap \dots \cap E_{1,n_1}) \cup \dots \cup (E_{m,1} \cap E_{m,2} \cap \dots \cap E_{m,n_m})$

Now, some of the events $E_{i,j}$ and $E_{k,l}$ might be *identical*. To compute the probability $P(A)$, the inclusion-exclusion principle has to be applied.

It seems that there is a possibility to rewrite $A$ as union of disjoint events, say:

$B=(E^*_{1,1} \cap E^*_{1,2} \cap \dots \cap E^*_{1,n^*_1}) \cup \dots \cup (E^*_{m,1} \cap E^*_{m,2} \cap \dots \cap E^*_{m,n_m})$

In that case, the probability $P(B)$ could be calculated as:

$P(B) = (P(E^*_{1,1})\cdot \dots \cdot P(E^*_{1,n^*_1})) + \dots + (P(E^*_{m,1})\cdot \dots \cdot P(E^*_{m,n^*_m}))$

Does this make sense? How could transform event $A$ into event $B$?

Comment: You may need a lot more details for the information "some events might be identical" to be useful for deducing that, if possible. And one general result: $A \cup B = (A \cap (B \cup B^c))\cup B = (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap B^c) \cup B = (A \cap B^c) \cup B$ - it is well known that $A\backslash B = A \cap B^c$ is disjoint with $B$ and their union will be $A \cup B$

Comment: So by identical, I really mean they are exactly the same. You could think of the event "Rolling a dice result in a $6$". Consider that exactly this event is both $E_{1,1}$ and $E_{m,1}$ in my above example. Does that make sense?

Comment: As I stated in the previous example, you can always partitioned a union into disjoint sets, as the most trivial example is by considering the relative complement. The question is whether these disjoints are easily constructed and calculated? And how did they related to your original set? In general this is not that easy. And the most important, key details missing here is that how identical event can help. I think it has to be work with case by case and you need to specify what is the pattern of the event. Which of them are equal?